# How to use URL regex in CherryPy?

Tags: python, web, cherrypy

I am trying to add URL regex to CherryPy, but for some reason, not everything works out. Where am I mistaken?

I need URL opts to look like example.com/opts/someopts.

But now with such a request, I get a 404 error.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, config):
         someactions

    @cherrypy.expose
    def opts(self):
        templ = Template(filename='dyn/opts.tmpl', lookup=self.lookup)
        self.token = random.randint(0, 99999999)
        return templ.render(opts=self.config, pageid='SETTINGS', 
        token=self.token, docroot=self.docroot)

d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.connect(action='opts', name='opts', route='/opts/:optsname', controller=opts)

conf = {
    '/opts': {
         'request.dispatch': d
     },
}
cherrypy.tree.mount(root=None, config=conf)
```

Comment: could you give more detail about what you are expecting and what you are seeing? Just saying it 404's gives us little to work off of. What is the actual request that 404's? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @minitotent I want my url to take any value after /opts for example /opts/somevalue, It doesn’t matter what the request is, the main problem is that the routing is not configured correctly, or rather not as I need, because of this I get page 404

Comment: While that's not something I have seen done a lot I don't see why it can't be done. Have you considered using query or fragments instead of making a new path? It's generally an easier way of getting data to your program: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

I'm also not seeing any use of regex here so I'm not sure why it is in the title. Might something like: "Dynamically create new paths in cherrypy" be a more suitable title?

I have only done a little with python web frameworks and it wasn't cherrypy but it used directories as paths and wouldn't automatically create new directories

Comment: @minitotent URL fragments aren't transmitted to the server side in HTTP requests.

Comment: @question_mark_77 have you tried to also add a route for `/opts/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is pass query string parameter somehow to the controller (Based on the comments you have added in the question), here is a simple example which (CherryPy 18.1.1):

```
import cherrypy

class Opts:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def opts(self, optsname):
        return optsname

d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.connect(action='opts', name='opts', route='/opts/{optsname}', controller=Opts(), conditions=dict(method=["GET"]))

conf = {
    '/': {
         'request.dispatch': d
     },
}
cherrypy.quickstart(None, '/', config=conf)
```